# How can I paste the content just after multiple lines

Tags: vim, macvim

I always face this problem in my real life.

**I want this:**

My cursor is at the first line of multiple lines of codes. The content should be placed just after multiple line of codes.

```
[cursor]xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
[this is where i want to place the code]
```

**The problem now:**

Since the `p` in vim just paste the code after the cursor, I have to go to the end of the lines and `p`.

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
[cursor]xxxxxx
[this is where i want to place the code]
```

Comment: You have a cursor in real life?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`put` is the command you are looking for

```
:[lineNo]put x
```

e.g.

```
:200pu
```

will paste the value of register `"` after the lineNo 200.

```
:200pu n
```

will paste the value of register `n` (before you may have done: `"ny`) after the lineNo 200.

for more detail, pls check `:h :pu`

**EDIT** for the `nu`

I feel it is nice  to use number or relative number in different cases. Not stick to one all the time. at least I am doing so. In my vimrc I wrote a little function to switch relative number and normal line number:

```
function! ToggleRelativeNumber()
    let &relativenumber = &relativenumber?0:1
    let &number = &relativenumber? 0:1
endfunction
"map <leader> rn to the function
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>nu :call ToggleRelativeNumber()<cr>
```

so I can type `,nu` to switch between them. (my leader is `,`)

Comment: it probably is the solution. But I am using relative number... :(

Comment: @code4j Lieven's solution should work for you. for the linenumber switching, please check the EDIT of in my answer.

Comment: About your `ToggleRelativeNumber()` function: This has changed in Vim 7.3.1115, see my answer at http://superuser.com/a/604625.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to paste after a block of code, you can use <kbd>}</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to navigate to the end of the block, then paste at that line.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. 
But it only works when the code is at the outer scope.
http://codetidy.com/5292/ Just like this codesm, you can only navigate to the end of the codes when the cursor is located outside `if`. When the cursor is located inside `if` and press }p, the cursor will go to the end of the outer scope

Comment: @code4j so then use a different appropriate movement. E.g. `$%p` to go to the end of the line, jump to the matching brace, then paste into below the current line. Spend some time reading `:h motion.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to paste from the default register,

- paste after next occurrence of `foo`:

  ```
  /foo<cr>p
  ```
- or Kent's suggestion:

  ```
  :+4put
  ```